# Common, accessible filesystem with very high filename size limit?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I need to extract an archive that contains files whose names are longer than 256 characters. Every common filesystem I have tried (ntfs, ext3, ext4) has a limitation on filename size at 255 or 256 bytes. Is there a filesystem I can easily use in a Debian system (mkfs, mount, etc) that helps me get around this limitation?

Comment: What filesystem was this archive created on/from?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know. It's an obfuscated jar that I'd like to analyze.

Comment: You could write a script in a language that supports zip files directly (e.g. Python) to extract the files with a different name.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this comparison of filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), it looks like the only one shipped with Debian that supports filenames longer than 256 characters is the (slightly notorious) `reiserfs`.

You can create and mount a new 100MB filesystem without needing to use a separate device like this:

```
# apt-get install reiserfsprogs
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/username/reiser-filesystem bs=1048576 count=100
# mkfs.reiserfs -f /home/username/reiser-filesystem
# mount -o loop /home/username/reiser-filesystem /mnt
```

Comment: Awesome; I tried this earlier but got stuck trying to `mount -t reiserfs`. This works. Thanks!